# PEPROCESS to PFILE_OBJECT

Tags: kernel

I am wondering what is the best way to convert a process object pointer over to a file object pointer. I am currently using this method:

1. pass PEPROCESS to ObOpenObjectByPointer to get handle to process
2. call ZwQueryInformationProcess to get ProcessImageFileName
3. call ZwCreateFile with ProcessImageFileName to get file handle
4. finally pass file handle to ObReferenceObjectByHandle to get PFILE_OBJECT

Any suggestions?

Comment: That's what I'd do. Don't know any shortcuts (such as getting the opened main executable image file).